# How you write collections (arrayList, vector, etc) as attribute in UML (Class Diagram)?

Tags: java, uml, class-diagram

I want to ask how I write collections (arrayList, vector) as attribute inside class diagram?

Because when you want to add variable as an attribute you can write it like "+ name: string", but how does it work with vector? Thanks.

Comment: I do not understand the vote to close because "needs details or clarity". Seems quite clear to me: How to write an attribute on a UML entity representing a collection of values such as what would be in Java an `ArrayList`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [this tutorial](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/multiplicity.html) on “multiplicity” and “multiplicity element” in a UML diagram.

## Cardinality

Follow the attribute name and type with an interval of one or two numbers in square brackets joined by 2 dots.

For exactly one:

```
goalKeeper : Player [1..1]
```

…or:

```
goalKeeper : Player [1]
```

For multiples, two to three:

```
forwards : Player [2..3]
```

Use asterisk for open-ended.

- Zero or more: `[0..*]`
- One or more: `[1..*]`

Must be zero: `[0..0]` or `[0]`

## Collection properties

Follow the multiplicity-range with characteristics of:

- `ordered` or `unordered` (meaning sorted)
- `unique` or `nonunique` (meaning distinct)

Nest those values in curly braces, separated by comma.

## Java

You said:

> I write collections (arrayList, vector)

By the way, never use [`Vector`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Vector.html). That legacy class was supplanted many years ago by [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html), as noted in the [Javadoc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javadoc).

Let's look at how the [Java Collections Framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_collections_framework) fits these properties.

A Java [`Set`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html) would be `{ unordered, unique }`. A Java [`SortedSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/SortedSet.html) or [`NavigableSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/NavigableSet.html) would be `{ ordered, unique }`. A Java [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html) would be `{ ordered , nonunique }`. As to the last combination `{ unordered , nonunique }`, no such interface nor implementation is bundled with Java; see the 3rd-party solution, [`Multiset`](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#multiset) in [Guava](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Guava).

[image: Table showing a Java collection class for each combination of ordered/unordered with unique/nonunique UML multiplicity property.]

## Example

Back to your example of some entity having names, say one or more names listed in order of preference:

```
+ names: string [1..*] { ordered , unique }
```

Your attribute name should likely be plural, such as `names` here rather than singular `name`.

Comment: Nice explanation!

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash Thanks. Please up-vote the Question, as it received an undeserved down-vote. I hate to see that happen with a new contributor asking a perfectly valid question.

Comment: @BasilBourque - Upvoted question too. I 100% agree with you.

Comment: In your last example, it would be better to write `String` instead of `string`, see chapter 21 'Primitive Types' of the UML specification version 2.5.

Answer (score 1):

The [answer by Basil Bourque](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62758658/10819573) is correct and to the point. This answer is just an addition to his answer.

When you want to depict a name, all you think of is that a name is a string of characters and thus, you do not mention in the class diagram whether it is `StringBuilder` or `StringBuffer` or `CharSequence` etc. You simply mention `String` which does not mean [String](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html) class.

Another example is `birthDate` for which you will simply mention `Date`; not `LocalDate`, `ZonedDateTime`, or `OffsetDateTime` etc. Here, `Date` does not mean the infamous `java.util.Date` class; it simply means a date type of object.

To summarize this, when you mention a collection, all you need to mention is the cardinality, not the exact implementation class (like `List`, `Set`, `Vector` etc.) e.g.

```
history: History[0..*]
```

means the attribute, `history` is of type collection and the elements will of type, `History`.

Answer (score 0):

in the same way you do for the other types, for instance `+ name: Vector<String>` because the type can be specified as a free text

Comment: @mtirtapradja ok, but is worth to mention that this implies an implicit or explicit profile to add new datatypes to the (very few) standard ones

Comment: Downvoted, because the UML specification, section 9.5.4, says that the type must be the name of a Classifier, not free text.